# My bathroom light and exhaust fan run at the same time

Tags: wiring, bathroom

I was wondering if it was possible to run a  a switch that can control the fan and light? I will add some pictures of the wiring, the black wire with no electrical tape is my hot line any help would be greatly appreciated. [image]

Answer (score 2):

Most fan/light combinations have two separate hot connections so that you can control the fan and the light separately. However, in order to do this you need 3 wires (a.k.a., "/3", which is black, red, white in a typical US cable) instead of just two wires. (And no, you can't take that bare copper wire as a spare - it is ground and, with very rare exceptions, can't be used as part of a regular circuit.)

Which means your options are:

- Run a new /3 cable (you can't just "add a wire") from a double-switch (replacing the single switch) to the fan/light
- Replace the fan/light with one that has a wireless remote control. This is quite common for ceiling fans/lights but I don't know if they are available for bathroom exhaust fans/lights.

Comment: Another option is to add an aftermarket remote module to control just the fan. Some are small enough to fit in a junction box. This would leave the existing wall switch to turn on the light. The fan would turn on by remote if wanted, but only if the light is already on. Turning off the wall switch would turn off light and fan. Look for a UL approved remote, using search terms such as "wireless light switch".

Comment: @MTA Good idea. Only catch is that if it is panel->switch->fan/light, as appears likely to be the case, then there is no "always hot" at the fan.